# How to navigate and validate through all the pages of a api response

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where the api returns payload response in pages if the payload has lot of data.

```
Request:
Background:
        * url url
        * call read('classpath:examples/common.feature')
        And header accesstoken = accessToken
        And header accept = '*/*'
        And header Accept-Encoding = 'gzip, deflate, br'


Scenario: Get Scores 
* param start = '2020-07-01'
Given path '/scores'
When method Get
Then status 200
* def totalPages = response.totalPages

* def response = {"requestId": "6a4287f35112",
    "timestampMs": 1595228005245,
    "totalMs": 51,
    "page": 1,
    "totalPages": 100,
    "data": [.......]}
```

After this i am getting total pages, and need to navigate through all the pages by passing the same request with additional * param page = #page_number and validate response is 200. page_number has to be iterated from 2 to 100.

Thought of using Karate loop or calling feature file and building dynamic data and using dynamic data driven feature, but not sure how to proceed.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest option is to write a second feature file and call it in a loop.

```
* def totalPages = 10
* def pages = karate.repeat(totalPages, function(i){ return { page: i } })
* call read('second.feature') pages
```